# Cesium : Primitive geometry hides label

Tags: cesium

I was trying to add a label and a primitive over the same area like so:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var scene = viewer.scene;

var instance = new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
  geometry : new Cesium.RectangleGeometry({
    rectangle : Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-130.0, 40.0, -115.0, 60.0),
    vertexFormat : Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance.VERTEX_FORMAT
  }),
  attributes : {
    color : new Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.8)
  }
});

viewer.entities.add({
        position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees( -122.19, 46.1914),
        label : {
            text : 'Some Text',
            font : '24px Helvetica',
            fillColor : Cesium.Color.WHITE,
            outlineColor : Cesium.Color.BLACK,
            outlineWidth : 2,
            style : Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL_AND_OUTLINE
        }
    });

scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.Primitive({
  geometryInstances : [instance],
  appearance : new Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance()
}));
```

The end result - the text appears under the image like so:
[image]

1. How can I add Label and primitive so that they don't hide one another?
2. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long-standing item on Cesium's roadmap/wishlist, made complex because Cesium needs to do proper 3D obscuration of labels (for example, when a labeled object is legitimately behind a mountain), but not when the user doesn't "think" the label should be obscured (for example, when the letters stick into the mountain).

Anyway, there's a workaround that can help in situations like the screenshot above.  Add this property to your label properties:

```
        verticalOrigin : Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM
```

The default origin is "Center" and that often causes the bottom half of all the letters to sink into the ground as shown above.  Moving the origin to the bottom of the label can raise the letters up such that they float above the ground polygon.  This doesn't fix every case but can make this issue a lot less noticeable (depending on usage conditions of course).